# How to handle saving of a ManyToMany relationship at the same time?

Tags: javascript, java, json, reactjs, spring

We have an enrollment form with two tables having a ManyToMany relationship.

- Client
- Account
- ClientAccount (Join Table)

Multiple accounts can be entered into the first screen.
Ex. `Account 1, Account 2`

Then in the second screen, multiple clients can be entered. And with each client, you can assign  multiple accounts.

```
Ex. Client 1 - Account 1,
    Client 2 - Account 1, Account 2
    Client 3 - Account 2
```

Both are newly created objects.

We use ReactJS as the frontend and Java as the backend. This is our current solution:

1. Pass two lists to the Java backend: List of accounts and list of clients with a list of accounts
2. Save all accounts.
3. Iterate through the client list:

```java
//save accounts first
for(Account account: accountList) {
 repository.save(account);
}

//iterate through client list then save the clientAccount entity
for(Client client: clientList) {
 repository.save(client);
 for(Account account: client.getAccountList()) {
   Account savedAccount = repository.findByAccountNo(account.getAccountNo);
   ClientAccount clientAccount = new ClientAccount();
   clientAccount.setAccount(savedAccount);
   clientAccount.setClient(client);
   repository.save(clientAccount);
 }
}
```

Is there a better way of implementing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks good from my point of view. I would implement batch save for both account and client.

Comment: You still could bypass the `findByAccountNo` this way: don't create accounts first. Just iterate over the client list. For each client pick the account from the account list and create the `Account` `A` if it is not already created. Keep `A` in a hashmap AccountNo->Account for lookups. But it's not really worth the hassle, I belive. I'd rather spend time for batching, as proposed.

Comment: Hi @user2809176, thanks for commenting! What do you mean by batch save? Are you referring to the repository.saveAll() method?

Comment: Not sure how your repository implementation works. Will it send a single request to backend/database on `repository.save()`? If yes tnen I would rather collect all the changes (e.g. for accounts) and after call `repository.batchSave(accountModifications)`

Answer (score 0):

Another way of implementing this is to have cascade on `@ManyToMany` relationship.

```
public class Account {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  [..]
  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(name = "account_client",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "account_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "client_id"))
  private List<Client> clients;
}

public class Client {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  [..]
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "clients", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Client> accounts;
}
```

and on save you would have the list of accounts which would have a list of clients and the cascade will take care of persists, updates, deletes.